# Tool to create a pdf report from a visual template

Tags: pdf, report, pdf-generation

EDIT: due to the lack of responses I've reformulated its title.

My goal here is simple: I want a tool to create a visual template (because I don't want to design by code) of a report (stats,charts etc), and then fill it with processed data from a database (thus needing a language to pull the data from the DB and to make all the processing.

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

This is a rather broad question, but still I've gone through some research and have not yet found any useful piece of information.

I used to use excel + vba to create a visual report and fill it with information from a database.

I'm looking for a alternative to that because 1) Excel has a lot of version issues (both excel and windows versions) and 2) I'm probably switching to linux.

So are there any keywords related to this process that I might do research on ?

Do you guys now any other languages/softwares/IDEs that can get the job done ?

Any means of creating this visual report both programatically or drag-and-drop ish style ?

Please answer asuming both that design is of ultimate importance and that it is not.

If there is room to choose my favorite language would be python for this matter. But no objections to any other. I haven't tagged python in order to not scare other languages programmers away.

Comment: This previous answer might be a good place to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177799/good-pdf-report-generator-tool-for-python

Comment: Awesome @Isowen ! exactly what I needed ! Still I'd like to keep the matter open to hear some other sides and possibly some other languages. but if you wanna answer with your link I'll be happy to accept it